# Make game for iPhone only

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

From the beginning of development on my game I was hoping to release it as a universal app, but the gameplay simply doesn't work as well on the iPad. Also, it was designed to work on the iPhone screen, and the (even slight) difference in width to height ratio gives iPhone users an advantage over iPad users by seeing more of the path ahead. Not to mention it doesn't look quite right on the larger screen.

Hypothetically, if my game becomes a top seller, would it be a bad idea to have it only an iPhone app? Would it make it far less likely for my app to become viral? My app would still work on the iPad like any other iPhone app, and I plan on eventually releasing an update that supports both iPad and iPhone.

Comment: This can't be answered. It's a hypothetical question. There's no correct answer to a hypothetical question.

Comment: It isn't hypothetical, I am asking if only supporting iPhone will dramatically decrease interest in my game.

Comment: Yes, that's not answerable with a *correct* answer. How could anyone know what the interest in your game will be? It would depend on the game, the audience receiving it and many other factors. The only answer you can get (and the one you got) would be "it depends". That's not a good question for the site. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about what types of questions to ask. Thanks.

Comment: you could always manipulate your iPad display to keep the iPhone screen ratio (add a border) it's not pretty, but it works, and if you already have a HUD on your game, you just have to stretch it a little. Just make sure you separate display, input, and game logic the best you can so it is easier to adapt your game to the system that works best. Also, unless you have multiplayer between devices, it probably does not matter if one device gives a slight advantage in game play over the other. As a side note, why is the word "multiplayer" not recognized by SE but "iPad" is? pure madness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It varies game to game, regarding Game Play.

If your game's Game Play is good for both iPhone & iPad, then it is bette to create for both devices.

- For example, ROVIO's Angry Birds

If your game becomes a top seller, then obviously you have to think about "viral" (Because there are many users at iPad). Then you have to make a good R&D whether it is possible to port at iPad.

And a good R&D will suggest whether it is better to create for both iPad and iPhone or still work on the iPad like any other iPhone app. Because here several issues arises regarding Game Play, UX etc.

Comment: -1 "If the game is good make it for both". How can you know the game is good before you create it? Just telling someone they need to "R&D" is not a good answer.

Comment: I am nearing the completion of my game, I just don't like how the game comes across on the iPad. So in my case his answer is perfect. PS, I would vote up if I had enough rep on this section of the site.